# ViewController does not have a member named tipCalc

Tags: ios, iphone, uipageviewcontroller, member, identifier

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TipCalculator
//
//  Created by Mathias Bakken on 6/28/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Mathias Bakken. All rights reserved.
//
```

I have 6-8 instances where I am receiving the error for not having the member tipCalc. I attempted to make an empty variable, but that only made things worse.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var totalTextField : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var servQualitySlider : UISlider!
@IBOutlet var foodQualitySlider : UISlider!
@IBOutlet var servQualityLabel : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var foodQualityLabel : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var resultsTextView : UITextView!
@IBAction func calculateTapped(sender : AnyObject){
    tipCalc.total = Double((totalTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue)
    let possibleTips = tipCalc.returnPossibleTips()
    var results = ""
    for (tipPct, tipValue) in possibleTips{
        results += "\(tipPct)%: \(tipValue)\n"
    }
resultsTextView.text = results
}
@IBAction func servQualityChanged(sender : AnyObject){
    tipCalc.servQuality = Double(servQualitySlider.value)/100.0
    refreshUI()
}
@IBAction func foodQualityChanged(sender : AnyObject){
    tipCalc.foodQuality = Double(foodQualitySlider.value)/100.0
    refreshUI()
}
@IBAction func viewTapped(sender : AnyObject){
    totalTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
let tipCalc = TipCalculatorModel(total: 33.25, foodQuality: 0.06, servQuality: 0.06)

func refreshUI(){
    totalTextField.text = String(format: "%0.2f", tipCalc.total)
    foodQualitySlider.value = Float(tipCalc.foodQuality) * 100.0
    servQualitySlider.value = Float(tipCalc.servQuality) * 100.0
    foodQualityLabel.text = "Food Quality 1-10 (\(Int(foodQualitySlider.value))%)"
    servQualityLabel.text = "Service Quality 1-10 (\(Int(servQualitySlider.value))%)"
    resultsTextView.text = ""
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    refreshUI()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}
I am getting a bunch of the same error messages saying "ViewController does not have a member named tipCalc"

I am also receiving the error "Use of unresolved identifier TipCalculatorModel"

How do I fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: You are using a variable tipCalc but there is no definition of this variable? Where have you defined this variable and it is instance of which class?

Comment: @rshankar It is defined look just above the third func from the end.

Comment: Ok I missed that one, Try to first fix the "Use of unresolved identifier TipcalculatorModel". Do you have this class in your project? If it is part of another module then try to import that class.

Comment: I do have 'TipCalculatorModel.swift' in the same folder. I thought it would pull it with the line I wrote. I will attempt to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation

class TipCalculatorModel{

var total: Double
var foodQuality: Double
var servQuality: Double
var subtotal: Double{
    get{
        return total / (foodQuality + servQuality + 1)
    }
}
init(total: Double, foodQuality: Double, servQuality: Double){
    self.total = total
    self.foodQuality = foodQuality
    self.servQuality = servQuality
}
func calcTipWithTipPct(foodQuality: Double, servQuality: Double)->Double{
    return subtotal * (foodQuality + servQuality)
}
func returnPossibleTips()->[Int:Double]{
    let possibleTipsInferred = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]
    let possibleTipsExplicit:[Double] = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]
    var retval = [Int:Double]()
    for possibleTip in possibleTipsInferred{
        let intPct = Int(possibleTip*100)
        retval[intPct] = calcTipWithTipPct(foodQuality, servQuality: servQuality)
    }
    return retval
}
```

}

I solved the issue by just pasting in the other module. Not a pretty fix. But it works. Thank you.